# ionic install npm error on window10

Tags: node.js, cordova, ant, ionic-framework

I installed nodejs,apache ant, JDK and android JDK.

after npm install -g cordova. so very good install!!

but... npm install -g ionic...

error code

```
C:\Users\dltls>npm install -g ionic
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\dltls\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\np
m-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.0

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\dltls\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-756-b0347231\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\-\ionic-1.7
.14.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: af493d5df4688d917d778b0934d1739b9be6efe6
npm ERR! Actual:   fab0cac875d9881f84f09df86dd8229035deb772
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-1.7.14.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dltls\npm-debug.log
```

I seach Internet... npm install -g npm and npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org and npm cache clean but error exist.. help me!!

Comment: `npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>`

Why don't you try doing that?

Comment: I resolve problom!!! thans~~

Comment: What was the problem? corrupt file, download again and it worked? or you have malware installed?